How to use locale to get "german" abbreviations within scale_y_continuous?
How can I change the locale to "de" so that "billion" is abbreviated as "Mrd." and million as "Mil."?

df_example <- tibble::tibble(
  
  year = c(2016:2023),
  tn = c(10:17),
  cost2 = c(10:17),
  cost = c(100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 20000000, 10000000000)
  
)



df_example |>
  
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y= cost, x= year)) +
  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale_cut = cut_long_scale()))


What I have tried is to set locale = "de" at several places within the scale_y_continuous() command.

TBMK there is no option to change the behavior of cut_long_scale based on the locale as the symbols used are hard-coded. But you use copy & paste to create a German version:
library(ggplot2)

cut_long_scale_de <- function (space = FALSE) {
  out <- c(0, "Tsd." = 1000, "Mil." = 1e+06, "Mrd." = 1e+9, "Bil." = 1e+12)
  if (space) {
    names(out) <- paste0(" ", names(out))
  }
  out
}


df_example |>
  ggplot(aes(y = cost, x = year)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(scale_cut = cut_long_scale_de(space = TRUE))
  )


